# Windows-like UI in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I am looking for some king of framework or library for styling web app to have a look of Windows application. I googled with no success, however I know at least one exists, because I had seen it long time ago. But now I can't recall its name or where to find it.

Is there a HTML/CSS library that would make my web app look like a Windows app ?

Please don't suggest jQuery UI or similar, because it's very far from what I am looking for (regarding UI design).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out Metro UI, a "front-end framework for developing projects on the web in Windows Metro Style": https://metroui.org.ua/.

The source code is also available from Github, here: https://github.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS.

Metro UI provides typographic styles and UI components such as application bars and keypads that have a strong correlation to the Microsoft's "Metro" interface, introduced in Windows 8. Metro UI is an excellent choice if you want to design a web-based app that has a similar look-and-feel to a native Windows 8 app.

Metro UI uses extended CSS syntax (Less) and is MIT licensed.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Fair point, @Guy, I've fleshed out my answer with a bit more detail for better future reference. I appreciate the constructive feedback. :)